# Taking out of silence after x missing calls from specific person?

Tags: notifications, silent-mode

I'm using silent/vibrate mode most of the time, however, I do want to be notified by a ring if a specific user/s called me more than once
Is there any setting or app to help with this request?

Comment: In Android 9: Settings > Sound > Do Not Disturb > Calls > Allow repeat callers

Comment: I know this one, but the problem is I have to set DND mode rather than just lowering the volume